# Get a number for a style value WITHOUT the "px;" suffix

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do some comparison logic about the positions of HTML elements. I have a system that I think should work, but there is a problem.

In my code I compare the current left and top values of one absolutely positioned element to those of another (which may be moving) using inequality statements (`>` and `<`).  The problem is that the feedback I get form `document.getElementById(nameVar).style.left` is in the form of a string (e.g. `200px`) not a number (e.g. `200`), so the comparisons don't work.

My question is, is there any way to turn the string into a number that I can manipulate the way I want to?  Either by using an altered address or by preforming some procedure with the feedback once I get it.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Regex way: `"10px".replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,'')|0` → `10` **or** `"10.px".match(/\d+/)[0]`

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`parseInt` gives you the numerical value:

```
var tmp = parseInt(document.getElementById(nameVar).style.left, 10);
console.log(tmp);
```

or, as @PeteWilson suggests in the comments, use `parseFloat`

Comment: One further wrinkle: sometimes x and y values are kept in partial pixels (at least on my XP machine in Firefox and Chrome). parseInt( ) chokes on those things. Instead of parseInt( ), I found I had to use parseFloat( ) which works great and has the added virtue of handling whole numbers, too. Maybe this is just an accident arising from my particular setup. But I've had this code running for six months and haven't had a problem. You might want to consider using parseFloat().

Comment: I think document.getElementById(nameVar).style.left.replace('px','') is a little more efficient

Comment: If you use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), please make sure to pass `10` as the 2nd parameter.  Behavior isn't always predictable when it's not passed.   `parseInt(x, 10)`.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos 1) don't microoptimize; 2) that still leaves it as a string, not a number, so e.g. `result + 5` becomes `"2005"` instead of `205`.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative approach to the one from [Konsolenfreddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690484/82548), is to use:

```
var numericValue = window
    .getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('div'),null)
    .getPropertyValue('left')
    .match(/\d+/);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VnE6J/1/).

The benefit of this approach is that it works to retrieve the value set in CSS, regardless of that value being set in the `style` attribute of the element or in a linked stylesheet, which I *think* [Konsolenfreddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690484/82548)'s approach is limited by.

References:

- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue)
- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: You probably need to add a `[0]` at the end of it all, to access the value itself

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.offsetLeft` and `.offsetTop` to get values without `px` and the return type is numeric.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/2sbvL/

Script:

```js
var result = document.getElementById( 'result' ),
    position = document.getElementById( 'position' );

result.textContent = position.offsetLeft + ', ' + position.offsetTop;
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="position"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
#position {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you are using CSS transition, the offsetLeft is different from the style.left property when the div is moving. Sorry for the downvote.

Answer (score 7):

You may also use:

```
element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

it returns DOMRect object (with some useful coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this issue with TypeScript:

```
const parseCSSNumericValue = (value: string, unit: string): number | undefined => {
    const match = value.match(new RegExp(`(-?\\d+)${unit}`))
    if (!match) return
    const [, g1] = match
    return Number(g1)
}
```

You have to provide a value like '10px' and a unit you want to catch, like 'px'.

```
const [x] = getComputedStyle(element).backgroundPosition.split(' ')
const pixels = parseCSSNumericValue(x, 'px')
```

It's because you do not want to get `10` when you want to parse pixels but there is a `'10%'`.