# Get line-height of element without 'px'

Tags: jquery

How do I retreive the line-height of an element without the "px"?

Using this I get the full line-height value including the px.

```
$('#example').css('line-height');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a number for a style value WITHOUT the "px;" suffix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690463/get-a-number-for-a-style-value-without-the-px-suffix)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Parse it as an integer with `parseInt`

`parseInt($('#example').css('line-height'), 10);`

Outputs:

`18`

As an integer. The other solutions maintain the String type.

**EDIT**

For values that may contain decimal points, you can use `parseFloat()`

`parseFloat($('#example').css('line-height'));`

Outputs:

`18.4`

Comment: Keep in mind that if your original `line-height` was set as a percentage and not pixels or ems/rems, using `parseInt()` will trim off decimals in your calculated `line-height`...

Answer (score 13):

Just replace the `px` with `''`.

`$('#example').css('line-height').replace('px', '');`

Answer (score 3):

save it into a variable an then make a replace

```
var aux = $('#example').css('line-height').replace('px', '');
```

Answer (score -3):

**In coffeescript**

```
getElementProperty = (el, property) -> 
  val = el.css(property).replace "px" , "" 

  parseInt val


getElementProperty $("#myElement"), "line-height"
```

This should to it !