# Parse CSS style marginLeft using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to parse the `marginLeft` property value of an `HTML` element using `JavaScript`, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have used both these methods (with or without the `,10`), but get "`Current marginLeft: NaN`" with my `console.log`:

```
var elementMargin = document.getElementById("main");
var style = elementMargin.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(elementMargin);

// tried this

var oldValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft, 10);
console.log("Current marginLeft: " + oldValue);

// or this

var oldValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft);
console.log("Current marginLeft: " + oldValue);
```

When I do a straightforward read and `console.log` of the property value, I do not get an error:

```
var elementMargin = document.getElementById("main");
var style = elementMargin.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(elementMargin);

console.log("Current marginLeft: " + style.marginLeft);
```

I get the output "**Current marginLeft: 199px**"

This is based on this post: [Get a number for a style value WITHOUT the "px;" suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690463/get-a-number-for-a-style-value-without-the-px-suffix)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]. Add the minimal amount of HTML to demonstrate the problem. Make it a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To clarify the answer in case anyone else has the same question (thank you to Quentin):**

```
var elementMargin = document.getElementById("main");
var style = elementMargin.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(elementMargin);

var oldValue = parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10);
console.log("Current marginLeft: " + oldValue);
```

Output: "**Current marginLeft: 199px**"

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you are getting the *computed* left margin, which will give you whatever the margin is after the stylesheet has cascaded.

In the second and third examples you are getting the left margin as specified in the `style` attribute. Since you are getting `NaN` this is, presumably, not set using the `style` attribute so is `undefined`.

Add `parseInt` to the code you used in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your response and help - much appreciated. Like this: `var test = parseInt(elementMargin.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(elementMargin));`?

Comment: Don't forget the radix.

Comment: I created this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onmyway/y4u752b8/10/ I would appreciate it if you could take a peek at what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You're running `parseInt` across the style object instead of the string with the number in it that you get from reading the `marginLeft` property of that object.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thank you.