# How to make document.getelementbyid.style.top a number

Tags: javascript

How to make document.getelementbyid.style.top a number?
I'm trying to make document.getElementById.style.top to be a number without px.
For example if document.getElementById.style.top is 100px, I want to make a variable that is 100 without px.

I tried to do this, but it wasn't working.

Comment: Use the `replace()` method to remove the `px` from it, then convert that to a number with `parseInt()`

Comment: Or just call `parseInt()`, it will ignore the `px`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a number for a style value WITHOUT the "px;" suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690463/get-a-number-for-a-style-value-without-the-px-suffix)  Googling for "style.top as number" had this question as the first result.

Answer (score 0):

```
parseInt(document.getElementById.style.top)
```

Comment: Even though this is a duplicate question, you should be using `parseFloat` instead.